# Why can a sigma bond rotate?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, atoms

My book says

> Because it (the sigma bond) lies along the line joining the two carbon atoms, the sigma bond can rotate about this axis.

But that doesn't make sense to me. So what if the sigma bond lies along the bond axis? How does that matter?

Comment: The sigma bond has symmetry akin to that of a cylinder. The energy is the same no matter what the rotation angle, thus rotation is possible. The energy does, however, depend greatly on separation of atoms as the balance of charges (protons/electrons) is upset. In a pi bond the symmetry is different and energy is needed to remove the p to p electron overlap on the two atoms, so free rotation is not possible.

Answer (score 10):

Sigma  bonds  are  defined as  having their  electron  density  along the  bond  axis, while  pi  bonds  have  their  electron  density  above and  below  the  bond  axis. What this mean is that pi bonds cannot rotate the same way as sigma bonds since rotation would break the pi bond interaction. See the picture below for clarification.

[image]

If you're wondering why it rotates then the more  freely  that  a  bond  rotates, the  more  favorable the entropy.  In  general, the  more  kinds  of  motions  and  the  more  unconstrained  those motions are, the  more  favorable the  entropy.